# Getting NullPointerException while implementing HashSet in Java using LinkedList for collision handling?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, nullpointerexception, hashset

I am studying Hashing. I am having trouble with add function.
I am trying to design a HashSet without using any built-in hash table libraries.

```
class MyHashSet {

    int setlength = 10000;
    LinkedList<Integer>[] hashSet;

    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public MyHashSet() {
        LinkedList<Integer>[] hashSet = new LinkedList[setlength];
        for (int j=0; j<setlength; j++){
            hashSet[j] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        }            
    }

    public int getHash(int key){
        return key%setlength;
    }

    public void add(int key) {
        int hash = getHash(key);
        System.out.println("Inside add");
        LinkedList<Integer> chain = hashSet[hash];
        chain.add(key);
    }
}

/**
 * MyHashSet object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyHashSet obj = new MyHashSet();
 * obj.add(key);
 */
```

I am getting Null pointer exception in the add function.
By debugging I have concluded that NPE is arising in line 4 of add()

```
LinkedList<Integer> chain = hashSet[hash];
```

But I am unable to understand why?

Comment: are implementing chain hashing?

Comment: @komatiraju032 Yes, I am trying to implement chain hashing aka separate chaining.

Comment: In your constructor `LinkedList<Integer>[] hashSet = new LinkedList[setlength];` change this to `hashSet = new LinkedList[setlength];`

Comment: The term for this error is *shadowing*.

Comment: Nice first question, by the way! Included all that was needed and you even debugged. Don't know why it got a down vote, that was not deserved. I voted up. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks! I am looking forward to contributing back here, some day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `hashSet` is null because you didn't initialize the member variable of the class, but created a new `hashSet` in your constructor. Use

```
/** Initialize your data structure here. */
public MyHashSet() {
    hashSet = new LinkedList[setlength];
    for (int j=0; j<setlength; j++){
        hashSet[j] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

instead.

(Difference: `hashSet = new LinkedList[setlength];` vs `LinkedList<Integer>[] hashSet = new LinkedList[setlength];`)